# Refresh data from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

First of all let me explain my situation.

- FORM_1 -> in dataGridView SQL table is shown, button for change data in specific row in this table
- FORM_2 -> open after button is clicked, data from selected row in FORM_1 can be edited in textBoxes.

I need to figure out, how to refresh table in datagridView after data from this table are updated in another form.

Basically I need to know in FORM_1 when FORM_2 was disposed or closed (FORM_2 is closed automatically if data are updated and saved into DB correctly) so I can refresh dataTable used to fill data in dataGridView

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, It´s too late (1AM)...

Answer (score 0):

With `ShowDialog()` Method. `Form1` code can wait until `form2` is closed. Then Reload Data. You can add a Boolean flag to check if data was changed or not and reload accordingly.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog(); // instead of form2.Show();
ReloadData(); // this will execute after form2 is closed;
```